# Show Elements froam a datatable by excluding all elements from another datatable

Tags: c#, linq, list, datatable

I have a few SharePoint Lists. I query one SharePoint List and Obtain certain Items based on what I require.
Now I have to query another SharePoint list and obtain list items from that list but my list items should exclude the items that I have Obtained from my previous Query.

Say My List has values A,B,C,D and E
From my first query, I get Values D and E.
Now my second query should be such that it should return only A B and C and I will then bind these 3 items to a dropdown.

How can we achieve this.
I am a novice to Linq or CAML queries.

Please help.

```
SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
                        qry.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Counterparty' />";
                        qry.Query = String.Format(@"   <Where>
                                        <Eq>
                                            <FieldRef Name='Fund' />
                                            <Value Type='Lookup'>{0}</Value>
                                        </Eq>
                                    </Where>", SelectedFund);

                        DataTable FirstDataTable = spList.GetItems(qry).GetDataTable();

SPQuery qry1 = new SPQuery();
                        qry1.Query =
                        @"   <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> </OrderBy>";
                        qry1.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' />";

                        DataTable SecondDataTable = spListCP.GetItems(qry1).GetDataTable();
```

My secondtable is more like the master table that will return A B C D E F G H values..Firsttable will return A b C D.
I wana show E F G H in the dropdwon.

PS: my previous query is a CAML query that returnds D and E

Regards,
Kapil Gosain

Comment: Please show us your code, so we can help you.

Comment: Alright, so both queries return only 1 column right? I suggest you use a List<string> instead a datatable. This makes the data manipulation afterwards a lot easier. But it isn't worth editing my answer in a large way, because `Except()` is just the method you want and need.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [Except()](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/ExceptOperator.ashx) operator

Using this is pretty straight forward.

lets say you have a list "allItems" returning A to E and a list "excludedItems" which returns D and E.

```
var allItems = from ... //returns A to E
var excludedItems = from ... where x == D || x == E //returns D and E

//output A, B C,     
var filteredResult = allitems.Except(excludedItems).ToList();
```

If you post some code on how you populate your list and query them, I will edit my code to be more specific to your individual case.

Kind regards

Comment: Added Code in the Question

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class t
    {           
        public string val { get; set; }
    }
    public class j
    {
        public string val { get; set; }
    }


public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var litT = new List<t>();
            var litJ = new List<j>();
            t objT = new t();
            j objJ = new j();
            objT.val = objJ.val = "A";
            litT.Add(objT);
            litJ.Add(objJ);
            objT.val = objJ.val = "B";
            litT.Add(objT);
            litJ.Add(objJ);
            objT.val ="C";
            litT.Add(objT);

            var result = litT.Where(p => p.val != litJ.Select(k => k.val).ToString()).ToList().Distinct();

            return View();
        }
```